# SQLite to TSQL - Case statement

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a query that was originally sqllight that I am trying to translate to MS sql server . fairly simple one but SQL Server doesnt like the line below give the error

***An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'WHEN'.***

```
CASE account NOT LIKE '%.restricted' AND usertype
```

I think it need to be more like below but the "and usertype" is not clear to me. The usertype in the database is 1 or 2 currently but it does allow nulls.

```
CASE when  account  NOT LIKE '%.restricted' AND usertype
```

```
SELECT username 
 
       ,Count(CASE account NOT LIKE '%.restricted' AND usertype  
                WHEN 1 THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
              END) AS Numberaccounts
FROM   users u
WHERE  u.Deleted = '' 
GROUP  BY  u.username
```

Not sure exactly how the and usertype is working in sqllite. I am thinking it would return true for any non zero or maybe non null. Not sure exactly how to rework that part.

Comment: There are 2 forms of case EXPRESSIONS (not statements). The simple form is the one you are attempting to use but that won't work. And for future reference, statements like "doesn't like" or "doesn't work" (or similar) are not helpful. When you get a syntax error here - post the complete error. You need to use the searched case expression which has the form "case when account not like ...". Note that "AND usertype" is incomplete and also needs to be corrected.

Comment: the error is a syntax error. It seems taht and usertype is incomplete but in fact it does work in SQLlite. 

The error in TSQL is 



"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'WHEN'."

Comment: Add requested information and explanation to your post - using comments for that purpose only buries important information that is difficult to find / read for future visitors. And you are learning a hard lesson here - just because some syntax works in one SQL dialect doesn't mean it works in another. Nor can I tell you how to correct the "and usertype" part - you need to understand what that query does in sqlite and then re-interpret / rewrite the query to accomplish the same goal in tsql.

Comment: Yeah, I think it goes without saying that there are differences hence the question.

Comment: Maybe `usertype` is some kind of boolean data type. Regardless please edit your question and add the exact T-SQL error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, `0` is evaluated as `FALSE` and any non `NULL` and non zero value as `TRUE`.
So the `CASE` expression can be written like:

```
CASE WHEN account NOT LIKE '%.restricted' AND usertype <> 0
```

which is also valid in TSQL.